# Doing a nav bar and headers on same line with flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make my header and nav bar appear on the same line using flex box, but the problem is that my h1 and h2 have to be side to side and the h1 and h2 to the left and the nav to the right.

This is my code:

```css
.heading {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>NAME</h1>
    <h2>JOB</h2>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div><a href="index.html">Gallery</a></div>
    <div><a href="about.html">About</a></div>
    <div><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `justify-content: space-between` on `header`.

```css
header,
.heading,
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
header {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>NAME</h1>
    <h2>JOB</h2>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div><a href="index.html">Gallery</a></div>
    <div><a href="about.html">About</a></div>
    <div><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div>
  </nav>
</header>
```